# Error when adding claim that contains json to custom policy in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have added Salesforce as IdP to Azure AD B2C using the OpenIdConnect protocol. And it works fine.

In the token from Salesforce I get a claim of type "custom_attributes":

```json
  "custom_attributes": {
    "UserRoleName": "SC Management"
  }
```

I now want to add that claim to the policy in B2C.
I add a "custom_attributes" ClaimType and add the claim as OutputClaim to to the ClaimsProvider and the RelyingParty (see below).

When I test it, it fails and I find the following error in traces:

"An unexpected type "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject" was encountered of the claim with claim type id "custom_attributes"."

How can I fix this error?

**Policy changes:**

In TrustFrameworkBase I add:

```xml
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
=>    <ClaimType Id="custom_attributes">
        <DisplayName>custom_attributes</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>     
        <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>        
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="custom_attributes" />         
        </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>             
      </ClaimType>
      ...
    </ClaimsSchema>
    ...
  </BuildingBlocks>
```

In TrustFrameworkExtensions I add:

```xml
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>salesforce.com</Domain>
      <DisplayName>Salesforce</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Salesforce-OpenIdConnect">
          <OutputClaims>
=>          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="custom_attributes" PartnerClaimType="custom_attributes" />
            ...
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
```

In SignUpOrSignin I add:

```xml
  <RelyingParty>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
=>      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="custom_attributes"  PartnerClaimType="custom_attributes" />
        ...
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
  </RelyingParty>
```

When I try to do the exact same thing with a claim that just contains text (not in json format) then it works.

Instead of passing the "custom_attributes" claim the whole way through to RelyingParty, I have tried to create a ClaimsTransform instead (it picks "UserRoleName" out of the token) but this requires "custom_attributes" as a OutputClaim in ClaimsProvider - and then I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you know the JSON structure being returned, and it is not dynamic JSON, you can use the [get claim from JSON transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/json-transformations#getclaimfromjson) in your `Salesforce-OpenIdConnect` technical profile's [output claims transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles#output-claims-transformations).

Example:

Claims to capture:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="SalesforceUserRoleName">
  <DisplayName></DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="custom_attributes">
  <DisplayName></DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

Claims Transformation:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GetSalesforceUserRoleNameClaimFromJson" TransformationMethod="GetClaimFromJson">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="custom_attributes" TransformationClaimType="inputJson" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="claimToExtract" DataType="string" Value="UserRoleName" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="SalesforceUserRoleName" TransformationClaimType="extractedClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Technical profile:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Salesforce-OpenIdConnect">
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="custom_attributes" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="SalesforceUserRoleName" />
    ...
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetSalesforceUserRoleNameClaimFromJson" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

In [REST API calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#metadata), you can use the metadata item `ResolveJsonPathsInJsonTokens` set to true, then in your output claims set the PartnerClaimType to the JSON path element you want to output. For example: firstName.localized, or data[0].to[0].email. - but I don't think this works for the openIdConnect technical profile protocols.

Comment: If I create a transformation, it uses "custom_attributes" as input claim. If I just add the transformation to the ClaimsProvider I still get the same "Unexpected type..." error.
If I then remove "custom_attributes" as OutputClaim in the ClaimsProvider, then I get another error: "A Claim of ClaimType with id "custom_attributes" was not found..."
It seems to me that it will fail if "custom_attributes" is an OutputClaim in the ClaimsProvider - and a ClaimsTransformation requires it's InputClaim to be an OutputClaim in the provider... But I guess it can be done in another way.

Comment: I've added sample code - Is this similar to what you have tried? Worth noting, all examples I've seen of this type of transformation either have the JSON claim UserInputType as `Textbox` or `Paragraph`... it is possible this is an undocumented requirement but as I don't have a working sample setup for JSON from an OpenIdConnect provider I cannot tell you for certain if it is or not.

Comment: Yes I have tried something similar - and now I have tried something exactly the same. Still the same error. The UserInputType doesn't make any difference. I have tried none, Textbox, Paragraph, Readonly.

Comment: I have also tried

`<ClaimType Id="custom_attributes">
  <DisplayName>custom_attributes</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>     
  <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>        
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType= **"custom_attributes.UserRoleName"** />         
  </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>   
</ClaimType>`

it doesn't give any errors - but it doesn't give any claim either. I suppose it only works with REST API calls.

Comment: If I get time today/tomorrow I'll setup my own policies with the OpenIdConnect protocol that returns JSON and try a few work arounds...